# Error when trying to print string with multiple lines

Tags: python, replit

I'm trying to make a tic tac toe game in Python but whenever I try to print the board, I get a weird error. Here is my code:

```
import os
from colorama import Fore


board = "   a     b     c\n     |     |     \n1  -  |  -  |  -  \n  _____|_____|_____\n      |     |     \n2  -  |  -  |  -  \n _____|_____|_____\n      |     |     \n3  -  |  -  |  -  \n      |     |    "

def board():
  print(board)

board()
```

And this is the error:

```
 SIGQUIT: quit
PC=0x7f1a62b22792 m=0 sigcode=128
signal arrived during cgo execution

goroutine 1 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.cgocall(0x4bb660, 0xc000066d90)
    runtime/cgocall.go:156 +0x5c fp=0xc000066d68 sp=0xc000066d30 pc=0x40651c
main._Cfunc_PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags(0x7f1a62be9800, 0x55555691b800, 0x0)
    _cgo_gotypes.go:418 +0x4c fp=0xc000066d90 sp=0xc000066d68 pc=0x4b8e4c
main.Python.REPL.func2(0x55555691b800)
    github.com/replit/prybar/languages/python3/main.go:122 +0x66 fp=0xc000066dd0 sp=0xc000066d90 pc=0x4bacc6
main.Python.REPL({})
    github.com/replit/prybar/languages/python3/main.go:122 +0x99 fp=0xc000066e10 sp=0xc000066dd0 pc=0x4bac19
main.(*Python).REPL(0x5d56d0)
    <autogenerated>:1 +0x2a fp=0xc000066e20 sp=0xc000066e10 pc=0x4bb36a
github.com/replit/prybar/utils.Language.REPL({{0x5075d0, 0x5d56d0}, {0x7ffd00c3ac79, 0x4e1680}})
    github.com/replit/prybar/utils/language.go:100 +0x5d fp=0xc000066e78 sp=0xc000066e20 pc=0x4b825d
github.com/replit/prybar/utils.DoCli({0x5075d0, 0x5d56d0})
    github.com/replit/prybar/utils/utils.go:77 +0x3d7 fp=0xc000066f60 sp=0xc000066e78 pc=0x4b8a97
main.main()
    github.com/replit/prybar/languages/python3/generated_launch.go:7 +0x27 fp=0xc000066f80 sp=0xc000066f60 pc=0x4b8bc7
<function board at 0x7f5f840e2280>
```

I haven't seen a error like this before and am wondering what it means and how to fix it? Thanks for help!

Comment: EXACTLY how are you running this script? The error message is from a "Go" application.  If you're in a web IDE, perhaps you have chosen the wrong language.

Comment: @TimRoberts im running this script off of a Python Repl on replit.com. I know replit uses Nix for Python but thats all I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are naming everything "board"

When you do "def board()" after "board = ..." you are redefining board to be a function and no longer a string.

The error you are getting is due to your editor somehow not supporting printing functions